# How to return a new state in redux with underscore?

Tags: reactjs, redux, underscore.js

When I am handling a reducer with underscore, not allow to use Object.assign since have to support the browsers.
 I write the reducer like this:

```
const actionHandlers = {
    [actionTypes.SELECT_OPTION](state, payload) {
        _.each(state.options, option => option.selected = option.value === payload.value);
        return state;
    }
};
```

Then I realize should return a new state, should not use each, since each has side effects will mutate the original one.

Then I replace each with map:

```
const actionHandlers = {
    [actionTypes.SELECT_OPTION](state, payload) {
        return [
            ...state,
            { options: _.map(state.options, option => option.selected = payload.value === option.value)}
        ];
    }
};
```

It seems like I assign the newly created object and return the new state without mutating the original one, but when I log them, the original state has been mutated too.

Any tip would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`state` looks like it should be an object with an `options` array?

Here is a non-mutating version:

```
const actionHandlers = {
    [actionTypes.SELECT_OPTION](state, payload) {
        return {
            ...state,
            options: state.options.map(option => ({ ...option, selected = payload.value === option.value })
        };
    }
};
```

In order for it not to mutate we need to spread (copy) each `option` as well.  Otherwise, it will reference the existing `option`.